# Why can I not specify a type (UInt) in a Julia function signature?

Tags: julia

I am writing some generic code to allow basic operations on functions.
It might be simplest if I give an example:

```
julia> import Base: +,^
julia> +(f1::Function,f2::Function) = x -> f1(x)+f2(x)
julia> ^(f1::Function, n::Int) = x -> f1(x)^n
julia> unity = sin^2 + cos^2
julia> unity(123.456)
1.0
```

So far, so good.
Now, say I notice that I want the second argument to be always positive, since raising a trig function to a -ve power implies an inverse function -- a totally different scenario.
Further, I probably won't even need a huge value for it, so say I decide to limit it to UInt16.

However,

```
julia> ^(f1::Function, n::UInt16) = x -> f1(x)^n
^ (generic function with 67 methods)

julia> unity = (sin^2) + (cos^2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ^(::typeof(sin), ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  ^(::Float16, ::Integer) at math.jl:885
  ^(::Regex, ::Integer) at regex.jl:712
  ^(::Missing, ::Integer) at missing.jl:155
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [2] literal_pow(::typeof(^), ::typeof(sin), ::Val{2}) at ./none:0
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
```

I don't understand the MethodError.  Why is:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ^(::typeof(sin), ::Int64)
```

somehow expecting an Int64?
and more importantly, how do I override it, to get the behaviour I want?

(PS. iow that the system handles the types appropriately, and the API user isn't obliged to use spurious casts, the target is an intuitive and predictable mathematical description language in the style of Sussman, of Scheme fame.)

Thanks!

Comment: You must write `sin^UInt16(2)`.

Comment: Exactly what behaviour do you want?

Comment: @SimenGaure  -  added brief explanation to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when given an integer constant, Julia's compiler looks at the format of the number and assigns it a type based on the format. Numbers in base 10 default to Int (**signed** Int64) and numbers such as 0x123 default to Unsigned integer types with the number of digits used in the constant used to assign the size of the unsigned type: 0x5 and 0x05 UInt8, 0x005 and 0x0005 UInt16, and so forth. So:

```
      julia> fpow(f, n::UInt16) = x -> f(x)^n
       fpow (generic function with 1 method)

       julia> sinpow(x, n) = fpow(sin, n)(x)
       sinpow (generic function with 1 method)

       julia> sinpow(pi, 5)
       ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fpow(::typeof(sin), ::Int64)
       Closest candidates are:
         fpow(::Any, ::UInt16) at REPL[13]:1
       Stacktrace:
        [1] sinpow(x::Irrational{:π}, n::Int64)
          @ Main .\REPL[14]:1
        [2] top-level scope
          @ REPL[15]:1

       julia> sinpow(pi, 0x5)
       ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fpow(::typeof(sin), ::UInt8)
       Closest candidates are:
         fpow(::Any, ::UInt16) at REPL[13]:1
       Stacktrace:
        [1] sinpow(x::Irrational{:π}, n::UInt8)
          @ Main .\REPL[14]:1
        [2] top-level scope
          @ REPL[16]:1

       julia> sinpow(pi, 0x005)
       0.0
```

But Julia will change a signed base 16 constant to unsigned (2s complement) without complaint.  Did you want this to work? It does:

```
       julia> sinpow(pi, -0x005)
       0.0
```

I would therefore suggest that, to avoid unneeded error messages, you use `Integer` in the function declaration and `@assert()` to require `n >= 0`:

```
function fpow(f, n::Integer)
    @assert n >= 0
    return x -> f(x)^n
end
```

or

```
fpow(f, n::Integer) = (n >= 0 || error("exponent cannot be < 0"); x -> f(x)^n)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, `@assert` may not be the right tool for this, since it can be disabled in some cases. I think it's better to throw an explicit error, for example a `DomainError`.

Comment: I usually want to be able to remove it when efficiency matters, but will add this.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'm new to Julia, still exploring the idiom, but I think I may use your suggestions if nothing better appears.  I'll think it over a couple more days before accepting.
I guess Julia does so much, sometimes elegance is not the top priority...

Answer (score 4):

`2 isa Int` (not a `UInt16`). Values don't have multiple types.